# IE10 writing directly into an 'Empty Text Node'?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-10, datatables

I've been doing a lot of testing in IE10 lately, and have recently ran into a very strange error.

Right after closing a jQuery UI dialog, IE10 opens up a cursor and allows the user type directly into the page. However, there are no inputs for them to be allowed to put things in, and from using Microsoft's F12 Developer tools, it seems that it is writing directly into the DOM -- an area that was a 'Text - Empty Text Node'. I have no idea where these nodes are coming from, or why the user can put text into one of them. I really have no code to show because it seems to be tied to nothing, and as I keep cutting away layers it still seems to be there.

Has anyone else ran into this? It seems to happen in IE9 as well. I'm at a loss here.

EDIT: In addition, I thought it may be helpful to say that I'm using [jQuery datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have made some progress on this.

It turns out IE10 isn't writing data directly into the DOM -- instead, it dynamically created a text input, didn't recognize it, and then deletes it. You can type directly into it, but if you click off or focus on anything else, then it disappears and leaves completely.

I've still not diagnosed the source of the issue -- I know it only happens in IE, and may include datatables or jQuery UI. I tend to believe it's IE specific, because it's such a rare action and there's no trace of it anywhere else.

Hope this dialog helps someone else down the line. If you find a better answer, please post it!